# Exchanging out of circulation Canadian dollar to US dollar in the US

Tags: united-states, foreign-currency

I have these Canadian dollars from 2010. I live in the U.S. Midwest. I have been to Wells Fargo, US Bank, and Chase branches and they all said it's out of circulation. It's not a lot of money. I am wondering where in the US I can exchange them for US dollars.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Those bills are still legal tender in Canada. https://www.bankofcanada.ca/banknotes/about-legal-tender/ is a government page that says so. "Out of circulation" is not a legal status but just something your bank feels like saying.

When I had old British notes that were no longer legal tender, British banks wouldn't change them for me (because I was not a customer) but British currency exchange places would. I recommend you call one of those (perhaps at your nearest airport) to see if they will help. Currency exchange is their prime function, unlike a bank for whom it's kind of a side thing they aren't necessarily very good at.